# Are there any apps to improve wifi priority sorting in macOS?

Tags: macos

I know how to sort wifi networks by priority in macOS, but the interface makes it a serious tedious task. I travel constantly so I have a tremendous number of wifi networks. Being able to search for networks and more easily set priority rules would be a great thing.

Are there any macOS apps out there to improve the interface on wifi sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use this one for quick and easy on the road access, WiFi Scanner.app

http://wifiscanner.com/wifiscanner.html

it's worked from osx 10.11 to 10.12.3, if you have an older version of OSX, check out KisMAC

if you want to dig deep into the packets for collisions, injections, penetration testing, etc, checkout Wireshark